# pgAdmin outputs "unable to connect to server:" error but does not specify the reason

Tags: postgresql

I have installed PostgreSQl and tried to create a new server on localhost:5432 in pgAdmin but it outputs "unable to connect to server:" error without any explanation why it occured.
My pgAdmin version is 4.28.

I have checked that postgres is running on that port.

Screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtF0L.png

Comment: Did you try a different tool, like psql, to connect?

Comment: What version of pgAdmin?  For me it always gives a reason.  I don't recall any version for which that part (for simple connections) was broken.  So maybe show a screenshot.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Do you mean I need to try to create a DB with CREATE DATABASE command?

Comment: No, just connect to the default database "postgres" using any PostgreSQL client, like psql.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Yes, I could connect to it.